# YARD: how to create a link to a class method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, documentation, yard

How do you create a link to a ruby *class method* with YARD? Here is the [yard documentation](http://rubydoc.info/docs/yard/file/docs/GettingStarted.md#Linking_Objects______) regarding links.

Linking to an *instance method* within the same namespace:

```
{#my_instance_method}
```

Which works fine. However, following that same approach with a *class method* does not compile, and modifying it:

```
{#self.my_class_method}
```

generates the following plain text (not a link):

```
ObjectName#self#self.my_class_method
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use the name, bare:

```
{class_method}
```

Or if it is in a different namespace

```
{Object.class_method}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a dot.

```
{.class_method}
```

Or, if you're using markdown as a processor, you'll need to escape the underscore.

```
{.class\_method}
```